# How can I change the Flutter test file search pattern from "_test"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I'd like `flutter_test` to find test files without the "_test" suffix. Where can I configure this pattern?

For python with pytest for instance, you'd change this setting in *pytest.ini*:

```
testpaths =
    tests
python_files = *.py
```

What's the Dart way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

I have gone through your question in-depth and I found these things.

1. I checked the test [package](https://pub.dev/packages/test) and dig deep into the source code to see how they were actually doing the checking for `_test.dart` files. And I found out that in the `pubspec.yaml`, they have one dependency called `glob` ([link](https://pub.dev/packages/glob))  which I think they used to filter the files. I went through their code and found these particular lines for it:

[image]

[Link to this page](https://github.com/dart-lang/test/blob/master/pkgs/test/doc/configuration.md#paths)

I tried to fork the repository and then change the type there but it was still showing the same test files as before. So I tried a different approach.

2. I tried to look into the VS Code plugin for test to see if I can change the type there but I couldn't found the exact module in which there defining the path. In VS-Code, we have an option in **settings.json** to search the test files outside of the test folder by this line.

`"dart.allowTestsOutsideTestFolder": true`

But there weren't any concrete options to change the test file search pattern for it. So my conclusion is if we were able to change the search pattern then we have to change in so many places which could also break some things. Therefore I would suggest to stick to the convention of it.

Answer (score 1):

Within Flutter there is no convenient option, you can specify which test files to execute. But this will result in an very heavy test script.

Such as:

```
flutter test test/file1.dart test/file2.dart ...
```

EDIT:

Based on the answer of Cavin Macwan. You can create an file in the root named `dart_test.yaml` with the following content:

```yaml
filename: "*.dart"
```

Note: This only works with `dart test` and not `flutter test`